# Lanzar Intent y volver a la app

Tags: android, activity, servicio

Estoy intentando lanzar la aplicación de las alarmas con el fin de poner una alarma en el sistema, pero quiero que, al estar la alarma puesta y activada, vuelva a mi aplicación.

He implementado esto a través de un servicio:

```java
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Alarm alarm = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.ALARMOBJT);
        alarm.updateTimeInMilis();
        int mode = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.INTDATA,-1);
        switch (mode){
            case Constants.AL_MOD_ADD:  // Add the alarm
                Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
                int hour = alarm.getAlarmDate().get(Calendar.HOUR) +
                        (alarm.getAlarmDate().get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM ? 12 : 0);
                int min = alarm.getAlarmDate().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR,hour);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES,min);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE,alarm.getName()
                        + "(" +alarm.getDetails() + ")");
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case Constants.AL_MOD_DEL:  // Delete the alarm
                break;
        }
    }
```

La clase alarma que he creado es la siguiente:

```java
public class Alarm implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    @Exclude private Calendar alarmDate;
    private long timeInMilis;
    private String type;
    private String details;
    private boolean deletable;
    private boolean active;
    @Exclude private Context context;
    // ...
    public void updateTimeInMilis() {
        alarmDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmDate.setTimeInMillis(timeInMilis);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el servicio, simplemente se pone la alarma y se queda abierto el gestor de alarmas del sistema. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que vuelva a mi app? O en su defecto, ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que este proceso sea transparente y no abra directamente el gestor de alarmas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar `EXTRA_SKIP_UI` .

En tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
     int hour = alarm.getAlarmDate().get(Calendar.HOUR) +(alarm.getAlarmDate().get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM ? 12 : 0);
                int min = alarm.getAlarmDate().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR,hour);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES,min);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE,alarm.getName()
                        + "(" +alarm.getDetails() + ")");
                startActivity(i);
```

Esto lo indica en la API:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock

Comment: Muchas gracias!
Es la primera vez que trabajo abriendo peticiones a otras apps, así que no tenía muy claro como hacerlo funcionar